# Could you paraphrase the last part of the following passage, please?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I am an easy going and laid back person, I love life and try to live to the fullest. One of my favorite activities is to smile and make people laugh, I feel there is so much negativity being projected into our lives that I want to bring happiness and light. There is so much that this life has to offer and I have chosen to be happy in it and be grateful for all the blessings that have been bestowed upon me. I lead my own experience and don't follow trends and/or people. I am an ambitious person and I believe I can have it all love, family, friendship and a career and I want someone who shares that same view and who encourages my success, **as will I with them and not be intimidated by it** .

I have some perceptions on it. Does it mean "as I will be with them" ? Is it kind of inversion? And they would not be intimidated by my success, does the word "intimidated" here refer to being jealous and being envious about your wife's  success?

Answer (score 1):

> ...and who encourages my success, **as I will encourage theirs**

They are looking for a partner who will encourage their success, and in return they will encourage the partner's success. You are spot on about the use of the word "intimidated" here. Some men feel intimidated by a wife that is more successful than they are, and may hold her back or withdraw their support if she becomes too successful. The author is saying that he will not do that.